# Splitting a number and concatenating split in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I’m working on a spreadsheet and have a Lot number I need to generate.  This lot number is made up of a W/O number + the last three digits of 110120 number

The W/O number is located in cell Q7 and the 110120 number is in cell B7

So I know I need to concatenate these two numbers together.  However 110120 number is 9 digits and I only want the last three so I think I need to split the 110120 number to have 6 digits then 3 digits, then concatenate W/O Number and last 3 digits.  Do you agree?

I have come up with the following code:

```
Private Function FSABT100LotNumber(value1 As Integer) As Integer

Dim strValue1 As String
Dim strValue1WONo, strValue1110120 As String
Dim value1WONo, value1110120 As Integer

'converts the values into strings for the Left() and Right() functions

strValue1 = CStr(value1)
Select Case Len(value1) 'gives a number depending on the length of the value1

Case 9 ' e.g., 902900123 = 902900, 123

    strValue1WONo = Left(value1, 6) ' 902900

    strValue1110120 = Right(value1, 3) ' 123

End Select

value1WONo = CInt(strValue1WONo)

value1110120 = CInt(strValue1110120)



Range("F29").Select

ActiveCell.Value = value1WONo & value110120



End Function
```

However, I know there’s something not right.  I need to tell the function that the W/O number is in cell Q7 and the 110120 number is in cell B7.  Problem is I’m not sure where I do this.

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Try adding a `Value2` to the function `Private Function FSABT100LotNumber(value1 As Range, value2 As Range) As String`, wehre value1 is cell B7 and value2 cell Q7.

Comment: Why trying to cut 1110120 if it's a constant and the result will always be 120? And you turn your strings into integers, by doing this you'll cut any leading zeroes that could be at the beginning of your WO or cut down value. Be sure that's what you want

Comment: What about putting the formula `=Q7 & Right(B7,3)` in the cell, where you want the lot number?

Comment: @danieltakeshi unfortunately your suggestion gave me an error "Compile error: Argument not optional".

Comment: @Fleury26 the 110120 number is not a constant it will always be a 9 digit number that I want to split and only use the last three digits of

Comment: @LJohnstone You will have to program all the other changes, using value2... And when calling the function you will have to make: `=FSABT100LotNumber(B7;Q7)`

Comment: @Jochen your formula worked, I am trying to make this spreadsheet purely VBA.  Is there any way of translating this to code?

Comment: @LJohnstone With your code, if you have, exemple, number "123400001" than strValue1110120 will be "001" and value1110120  only "1", so you'll be missing 2 digits, same if your WO had leading zeroes